# Maximizing $\frac{(1 + |x|)(1 + |y|)}{(1 + |x + y|)^2(1 + |x - y|)^2}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

Consider the function $$f(x, y) := \frac{(1 + |x|)(1 + |y|)}{(1 + |x + y|)^2(1 + |x - y|)^2}.$$ Is there a way to show rigorously that $f$ attains a global maximum at $(0, 0)$?

Plotting this function in Mathematica for $(x, y) \in [-10, 10]^2$ gives the following picture which at least makes this claim seem plausible, but I am unable to prove this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. By AM-GM, we have
$$(1+|x|)(1+|y|)\le\left(\frac{(1+|x|)+(1+|y|)}{2}\right)^2 = \left(1+\frac{|x|+|y|}{2}\right)^2. $$
By the triangle inequality, we have
$$|x| = \left|\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{x-y}{2}\right|\le\frac{1}{2}(|x+y|+|x-y|) $$
and similalry $|y|\le\frac{1}{2}(|x+y|+|x-y|)$ as well. It follows that
\begin{align} 1+\frac{|x|+|y|}{2}&\le 1+\frac{|x+y|+|x-y|}{2} \\
&\le 1 + |x+y| + |x-y| + |x+y||x-y| \\
&= (1+|x+y|)(1+|x-y|)
\end{align}
so
$$(1+|x|)(1+|y|) \le \left(1+\frac{|x|+|y|}{2}\right)^2 \le (1+|x+y|)^2(1+|x-y|)^2.$$
Thus, $f(x,y) = \frac{(1+|x|)(1+|y|)}{(1+|x+y|)^2(1+|x-y|)^2}\le 1$ for all $x,y$. Equality holds at $(x,y) = (0,0)$, so $f$ attains a global maximum at $(0,0)$.